# Rotation matrix about a $3-D$ axis

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, rotations

I have eventually end up rotating a point in $\mathbb {R^3}$n .

Let **r**$=(-1,-1,-1)$ orient the line L it spans, and let $R: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ be the rotation of $\mathbb{R^3}$ about $L$ according to the right hand rule along the angle $\theta= \frac{\pi}{6}$.

$a)$ FInd **u**, the unit vector in the rirection of **r**.

This was simple. $||u||=\sqrt{3}$ so **u**$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(-1,-1,-1)$

$(b)$ Find an orthonormal basis $\text{{$\bf a$,$\bf c$}}$ of the orthogonal compliment of *L*.

How would I do this? Since I am in $\mathbb{R^3}$, I feel like I could avoid using the gram schmidt process and use the cross product somehow. What does it mean by "orient the line it spans" though? I feel like I wrote the equation of a plane $-x-x-z=0$ or essentially $x+y+z=0$. So Maybe I could find two other points and cross them with each other to get an orthonormal basis?

I am not completely sure about this.

$(c)$ Using the vectors **a**,**c** and **u**, create an ordered orthonormal basis $B=a,b,u$ of $\mathbb{R^3}$, where $b= \pm c$ is chosen so that the triple $(\bf a, \bf b,\bf c)$ has the right hand orientation of $\mathbb{R^3}$

Is this not the same as part b? I am lost on this part... If someone could explain this, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that instead of $(-1, -1, -1)$ the vector $r$ was $(0, 3, 0)$. Then the answers would be

(a) $(0, 1, 0)$, as you know.

(b) $a = (1, 0, 0), c = (0, 0, 1)$. Note, though, that $a, c, r$ is **not** a positively oriented basis.

(c) Since $a, c, r$ is not positively oriented, we know that $a, -c, r$ **is** positively oriented.

Now you need to rotate by $\pi/6$ in the $a,-c$ plane...but I leave that to you.

Oh...by the way, for part b, there are infinitely many answers. So a good approach is to try to find a vector $a$ with, say, the $z$ coordinate being zero; that reduces your choices a good deal. And then yes, you can find $c$ as a cross product of $a$ and $r$ (or $r$ and $a$, or do something else and then use gram-schmidt)

Comment: Why do we have to positively orient it? What's the importance of that?

Comment: Well...you have to because part c tells you to create an ordered basis with right-hand orientation, which is also called "positive orientation". Why do you care? Well, if you move $a$ by $\pi/6$ towards $c$, that's a different rotation than you get by moving $a$ by $\pi/6$ towards $-c$, and it's the SECOND one that you want. (at least in my contrived example)